# Not recognizing Null value in Laravel Validation Rule with Condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-validation

Laravel version: 7.0

I am going to validate using `exists` with extra condition.

My validation rule is as following:

```
$rule['id'] = 'required|exists:domains,id,website_id,null';
```

I was going to validate if `id` exists in `domains` table where `website_id` is `null`.

Even there there are some rows which meet above rule, it returned validation error message: `selected id is invalid`.

I think system consider `null` as string 'null'.

So I tried like this.

```
$rule['id'] = 'required|exists:domains,id,website_id,' . null;
```

But same error.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried by using the `Rule` class? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-exists   or with `'NULL'` as the value ?

Comment: Woo, just NULL worked for me. Thank you!!! Please post answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'NULL'` as the value. It specifically looks for this value for when you want to do a `WHERE NULL` with the database related rules.